# Max-Weight-Clique and Max-Weight-Stable-Se

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization

Let G = (V, E) be a simple undirected graph and $c ∈ Z^V$ weights on the nodes of G.

A vertex set C ⊆ V is called Clique if {u, v} ∈ E holds for all u, v ∈ C, with u not equal to v.

A node set S ⊆ V is called stable set if {u, v} doesn't belong to E holds for all u, v ∈ S, with u not equal to v.

**Max-Weight-Clique**
Given: Graph $G = (V, E), c ∈ Z^V$
Find: a c-maximizing clique C ⊆ V

**Max-Weight-Stable-Set**
Given: Graph $G = (V, E), c ∈ Z^V$
Find: a c-maximizing stable set S ⊆ V

Does anyone know how to prove the problem Max-Weight-Clique is polynomial reducible to Max-Weight-Stable-Set and vice versa?

I can't find any references, proofs or anything, so I am not even sure where to start or how such a proof would go,

Comment: Here's a start: clique in $G$ iff stable set in the complement of $G$

Comment: thank you, but honestly doesn't really help to understand